# Arrays and nested foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two array output (using `preg_match_all`), for example: `$name[1]` and `$family[1]`.

i need to put these arrays together, and i use `foreach` as this:

```
foreach( $name[1] as  $name) {
    foreach( $family[1] as  $family) {
    echo  $name.$family.'<br />';
   }
}
```

but it don't work.

(each `foreach` loop works separately)

Comment: Why are including a key (the '[1]') in the foreach?

Comment: without 1 i dont get (and printed) string values of arrays.

Comment: There is no loop if you use the key. There is only 1, $name[1]. There might be a hundred keys in the array $name[1]...$name[100]. But you are naming the key, no loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they have matching keys for the loop:

```
foreach( $name as $key => $value) {

    echo  $value[$key] . $family[$key] . '<br />';

}
```

This will go through each match for `$name` and print it out, and then print out the corresponding `$family` with it. I don't *think* you want to hardcode `[1]`.

If you do, I'm a little confused and would like to see a `var_dump` of both `$name` and `$family` for clarification.

Comment: Correct idea, but you must not use $name twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$together= array();
foreach( $name as $key => $n) {
   $tuple= array('name'=>$name[$key],'family'=>$family[$key]);
   $together[$key]= $tuple;
}

foreach( $together as $key => $tuple) {
   echo "{$tuple['name']} {$tuple['family']}<br />"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

> Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and
>   the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

**PHP CODE:**

```
$nameFamilly=array_combine($name[1] , $family[1]);
foreach(  $nameFamilly as  $name=>$familly) {

    echo  $name.$family.'<br />';

}
```